# error: no such command: `+solana`

Tags: anchor, solana-cli

I using anchor init source, after use anchor build to build and i get error:
info: uninstalling toolchain 'solana'
info: toolchain 'solana' uninstalled
error: no such command: `+solana`

```
    Cargo does not handle `+toolchain` directives.
    Did you mean to invoke `cargo` through `rustup` instead?
```

Version solana: solana-cli 1.17.13 (src:ef1fb9ec; feat:4006346914, client:SolanaLabs)
Version rustup:
rustup 1.27.0 (bbb9276d2 2024-03-08)
info: This is the version for the rustup toolchain manager, not the rustc compiler.
info: The currently active `rustc` version is `rustc 1.77.0 (aedd173a2 2024-03-17)`

How to fix, plsss